# Execution plan caching of ITVF called with inline vs dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, dynamic-sql, parameter-sniffing

I would like someone to explain to me how each of the two queries below would generate their execution plan in SQL Server where my function `[dbo].[GetAdditionalProjectDatesForCalendar]` is an ITVF (inline table-valued function):

**Dynamic SQL**

```
sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GetAdditionalProjectDatesForCalendar]
(@Parameter1,@Parameter2)', @Parameter1 = 'Value1', @Parameter2 = 'Value2'
```

**Inline SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GetAdditionalProjectDatesForCalendar]
('Value1','Value2')
```

#### Background

The Dynamic SQL is what's generated from a C# application that I'm working on and while it performs just as well as the Inline SQL most of the time it performs poorly for certain values of `@Parameter1` and `@Parameter2`.

I've read up on how this is caused by [Parameter Sniffing](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options) and I've tried using `option(recompile)` with the Dynamic SQL but that hasn't improved the performance entirely.

I feel like I need to find a way to force C# to create the Inline SQL so that it will use the exact execution plan for the given parameters instead of creating one on the fly with `option(recompile)`.  I also think I can do this by writing my dynamic sql without using parameterization but I know that would introduce a SQL Injection risk.

Comment: If you scroll down to the "Little Known Wonders" header of this article, there's some explanation for what you're seeing, and potential workarounds. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/121906/

Answer (score 3):

The `sp_executesql` plan with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` should be fully optimized for the specific parameter values on each call, with parameter embedding also enabled.

Taking the [AdventureWorks](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks) example from Itzik Ben-Gan's comment on the article referenced in the question:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.F
(
    @NameLike nvarchar(50),
    @Sort tinyint
) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT TOP (5)
        ProductID,
        Name
    FROM Production.Product
    WHERE
        @NameLike IS NULL
        OR Name LIKE @NameLike
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @Sort = 1 THEN ProductID ELSE NULL END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @Sort = 2 THEN ProductID ELSE NULL END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @Sort = 3 THEN Name ELSE NULL END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @Sort = 4 THEN Name ELSE NULL END DESC;
```

The execution plan for:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.F(N'K%', 3);
```

...shows the specific parameter values being inlined (so the `@NameLike IS NULL` is optimized away, enabling a seek) but parameter embedding does not take place so there is a Top N Sort for the `ORDER BY` clause:

[image: inlined values only]

If we add the recompile query hint, a plan is generated for the specific values with parameter embedding enabled (so no sort):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.F(N'K%', 3)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

[image: inlined plus peo]

If we wrap the query in `sp_executesql` we get neither inlining nor embedding, since the values are explicitly parameterized:

```
EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql
    N'SELECT * FROM dbo.F(@NameLike, @Sort)',
    N'@NameLike nvarchar(50), @Sort tinyint',
    @NameLike = N'K%', @Sort = 3;
```

[image: parameterized]

Adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` enables both optimizations again:

```
EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql
    N'SELECT * FROM dbo.F(@NameLike, @Sort) OPTION (RECOMPILE)',
    N'@NameLike nvarchar(50), @Sort tinyint',
    @NameLike = N'K%', @Sort = 3;
```

[image: inlined and embedded]